# Change the node while transaction is still pending?

Tags: transaction, pending, node

What happens if I change the node while the transaction is still pending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wallet doesn't keep an open connection to the full node. Here is the flow :

- get the tips (connection required)
- do the pow (offline)
- post the transaction (connection required)
- transaction is pending (no connection required)

Changing the node when you have a pending transaction has no impact on anything.

Comment: the transaction may "disappear" in case it has not yet broadcast to the other node. But that is unlikely.

Comment: @Mihi right if you shutdown the fullnode that just receive the transaction. But my understanding of the question was "what append if you change the fullnode of the light wallet when a tx is pending ?"

Comment: Depending on how many neighbors are between your full nodes, it can also happen if the full node is not shut down. Also, there could be network problems and while a node will re-request confirmed transactions earlier or later (when it tries to make the next milestone solid), this might not happen with unconfirmed transactions (being the reason why the number of tips can be different between nodes on http://iota.dance/nodes)